# Randomly move instanced mesh along y-axis three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a grid of instanced meshes (boxes) that are positioned randomly on their own y-axis using `Math.random()` in THREE.js

Here is my code producing the grid of boxes:

```
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.95, 0.95, 0.95 ); 
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
        color: 0xffffff,
        metalness: 1,
        roughness: 0,
        wireframe: false
    } ); 
    const cube = new THREE.InstancedMesh( geometry, material, 2500 ); 
    scene.add( cube );

    let rows = 60;
    let columns = 60;
    let index = 0;
    const box_dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
    for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            box_dummy.position.set((i - rows / 2) + 2, 0 + Math.random(), (j - rows / 2) + 2);
            box_dummy.updateMatrix()
            cube.setMatrixAt(index++, box_dummy.matrix)
        }
    }
```

And here is a picture of the output:
[image: picture of grid of meshes]

The problem I'm facing is I want them to be moving up and down on their own y-axis. If I'm describing it poorly, an example of what I mean can be found at this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaXb-hH2BIg) with the timestamp of the video showing the effect I want is 30 minutes 16 seconds (30:16).

My guess was that I needed to traverse through the scene and get each instance of the original mesh, then apply a method for each instance with something like `mesh.position.y = Math.sin( time ) * 20 + 5;` to give that up-down effect.

The problem I'm facing was that each mesh y-axis position was all the same - meaning there was no stagger effect like in the image I attached or the video I linked to - they all moved up and down, but all in unison which created a flat surface rather than individually based on their original position.

**Basically, in a summarization, I want the staggered effect like in my own image attached, but each mesh moving along individual y-axis paths randomly like in the video I linked to. How would I go about doing this?**